# Upload file shows Error Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I tried to take it off this error I do not understand why it happens, because I am uploading the file correctly... Right now is uploading the files, it shows me the error Error Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in...

```
      <?php
   if(isset($_FILES['csv'])){
      $errors= array();
      $file_name = $_FILES['csv']['name'];
      $file_size = $_FILES['csv']['size'];
      $file_tmp = $_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'];
      $file_type = $_FILES['csv']['type'];
      $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['csv']['name'])));// error line

      $expensions= array("csv");

      if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
         $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a csv file.";
      }

      if($file_size > 2097152) {
         $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
      }

      if(empty($errors)==true) {
         move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/".$file_name);
         echo "Success";
      }else{
         print_r($errors);
      }
   }
?>
<html>
   <body>

      <form action = "" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
         <input type = "file" name = "csv" />// If I change this to name this code does not works, 
         <input type = "submit"  value="Subir archivos"/>


      </form>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you sure it's this code causing the notice? No line number/file? Which line of code is it referring to?

Comment: it is this one  $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['csv']['name'])));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When calling [`end()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php), you must pass an array as a variable and not the return value of a function.  So in...

```
$file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['csv']['name'])));
```

you can assign the return of `explode()` to a variable and then call `end()`

```
$file_parts =explode('.',$_FILES['csv']['name']);
$file_ext=strtolower(end($file_parts));
```

If you look at the documentation for `end()`, it shows the paramter is `array &$array`, the `&` shows it's passed by reference.

Answer (score 0):

It complains when you don't pass a plain variable in. It doesn't like functions being passed in.

Also you already assign `$_FILES['csv']['name']` as `$name`, so just use `$name`.

Split the line up:

```
$file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['csv']['name'])));
```

To

```
$file_ext = explode('.',$name);
$file_ext = end($file_ext);
$file_ext = strtolower($file_ext);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
$file_ext = strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['csv']['name'])));
```

To this:

```
$file_ext = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

And regarding the `If I change this to name this code does not works`, that is because you also need to change the array index to `name` on the `FILES` superglobal to access the data.

```
if (isset($_FILES['name'])) {
    $errors = [];
    $file_name = $_FILES['name']['name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['name']['size'];
    // and so on...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

end — Set the internal pointer of an array to its last element.
Separate into different variables. this should work

```
$file_exploding =explode('.',$_FILES['csv']['name']);
$file_last_element = end($file_exploding);
$file_ext=strtolower($file_last_element);
```